# Operation on server time using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, time

I have table in MySQL as shown below. You can see I have inTime and outTime columns and where you found inTime by default outTime will be 00:00:00 and vice versa. I want to calculate total_inTime for a any single date in such a way that addition of all differences between intime and outTime. (first_outTime-first_inTime like this).

[image]

How can I calculate total_inTime from this and how to do operations on inTime and outTime which is in HH:mm:ss format in c#?

Comment: use `TimeSpan` to calculate the difference between the in and out time.

Comment: Well, Let me try. I think its good solution. Sir, Can you tell me how to get data from mysql to in proper manner so that such operations will be easy to do.

Comment: use the `SqlDataReader` object.

Comment: OK. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Example:

```
DateTime inTime = Convert.ToDateTime("17:19:44"); //example inTime
DateTime outTime = Convert.ToDateTime("19:19:00"); //example outTime
TimeSpan span = outTime - inTime;
TimeSpan duration = span.Duration();
Console.WriteLine(duration);
```

Output:

> 01:59:16

For performing the operation on your Table, do something like this:

```
MySqlDataReader mydr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (mydr.Read())
{
    DateTime inTime = Convert.ToDateTime(mydr["inTime"]);
    DateTime outTime = Convert.ToDateTime(mydr["outTime"]);
    ...
    ...
    //the rest of the code goes here as in the example.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply in detail. Let me check.